# Android ListView - items from Array[JSON]

Tags: java, android, android-listview

How could I add items from listView(on my layout) from array?
I tried multiple times, but everytime <strike>I get error: `System services not avaliable before onCreate.();`. Yes, I. know that  this er.ror is shown when I try to access `ArrayAdapter`. Tried almost everything. .Full code is here: [pastebin.com/Nv5BkcS7](http://pastebin.com/Nv5BkcS7)</strike>

**UPDATE**

I followed some other tutorials. My code works now, but there is no data. http://pastebin.com/D8UFKC7i and xml http://pastebin.com/mJfwjGcB
Could someone tell me why it doesn't work.?  Debugger says that arrays have all entires

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.create a custom Adapter exteding BaseAdpter or ArrayAdpter and pass array or ArrayList in constructor.

2.Create the View in layout (of row )

3.inflate this xml in getview function of custom Adapter and set the data.

Activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<ListView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/lstText"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

list row XML (in layout row.xml)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/txtAlertText" />

  </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Create Adapter Class inside your activity

```
 class JSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

private final Activity activity;
private final JSONArray jsonArray;
private JSONAdapter (Activity activity, JSONArray jsonArray) {
    assert activity != null;
    assert jsonArray != null;

    this.jsonArray = jsonArray;
    this.activity = activity;
}


@Override public int getCount() {
    if(null==jsonArray) 
     return 0;
    else
    return jsonArray.length();
}

@Override public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
     if(null==jsonArray) return null;
     else
       return jsonArray.optJSONObject(position);
}

@Override public long getItemId(int position) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = getItem(position);

    return jsonObject.optLong("id");
}

@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);



    TextView text =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlertText);

                JSONObject json_data = getItem(position);  
                if(null!=json_data ){
                String jj=json_data.getString("f_name");
                text.setText(jj); 
               }

     return convertView;
}
 }
```

Then add this in your activity.

```
  public class main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ListView lstTest;
//Array Adapter that will hold our ArrayList and display the items on the ListView
JSONAdapter jSONAdapter ;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //Initialize ListView
    lstTest= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstText);


    jSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter (main.this,jArray);//jArray is your json array 

    //Set the above adapter as the adapter of choice for our list
    lstTest.setAdapter(jSONAdapter );


}
```

And you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Java throws exception  `An error occured while executing doInBackground()`
Probably is't because I didn't put it in onCreate(), but I have to load contact list after checking login so after one of my background task. Here is my new paste: http://pastebin.com/84nKS7VQ

Answer (score 2):

Your onCreate() method is blank in the addcontacts activity, thats the problem:

```
public class addcontacts extends ListActivity {

                 protected void onCreate() {
                      //set content here                       
                      setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);
                 }
                 ...
   ...
```

And Don't forget to create activity_add_contact.xml in Layout folder

with content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Now application get stuck on onCreate()